# Show extra property in Jquery Autocomplete Suggestion e.g. show both First & Last Name during search

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm using jquery autocomplete feature. I would like the suggestion list to show the lastname field too. This will help user select the right option especially when there are 2 or more identical first names in the suggestion list. I will appreciate any assistance from you.
[image]

```
<input type="text" name="names" id="names"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="au/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="au/src/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

<script>    
   var names = [
    { value: 'Jason', lastname: 'Borne' },
    { value: 'Jason', lastname: 'Derulo' },
    { value: 'Roberto', lastname: 'Carlos' },
    { value: 'Denzel', lastname: 'Washington' }
    ];

    $('#names').autocomplete({
    lookup: names,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ' ' + suggestion.lastname);
        }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you considered {value: 'Json Borne'} as elements in names array, or are you looking for a more elegant solution, presumably passing extra params to autocomplete to indicate to it that it should also display last names.

Comment: Yes, that would one of the way to do it, however i wanted to know how to do it with the code. Its useful to know how because i have another autocomple for location, there are some identical places and one way to give a hint to user is to show the value(location) with state in the suggestion list.

Comment: Do know how to do it Jarek? I will be so thankful if you have a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a **better solution** that will support a **big data** and work without delays on showing additional suggestion field e.g. instead of autocomplete only showing value (firstname), i needed the autocomplete to show 2 properties instead, the value and lastname.

[Solution jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tamimi89/53L5kyum/)

[image: 2 suggestions showing up in autocomplete]

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-flexdatalist/2.1.3/jquery.flexdatalist.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js?ver=1.12.3'></script>    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-flexdatalist/2.1.3/jquery.flexdatalist.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="fullnames" id="fullnames"/>
```

I changed the autocomplete plugin to [jQuery.flexdatalist](http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/)

```
var names = [
    { value: 'Jason', lastname: 'Borne' },
    { value: 'Jason', lastname: 'Derulo' },
    { value: 'Roberto', lastname: 'Carlos' },
    { value: 'Denzel', lastname: 'Washington' }];

    $('#fullnames').flexdatalist({
    minLength: 2,
    selectionRequired: true,
    visibleProperties: ["value","lastname"],
    searchContain: true,
    searchIn: 'value',
    searchDelay: 300,
    noResultsText: 'No results found for "{keyword}"',
    data: names
}).on("select:flexdatalist",function(event, data){
    // do something when user selects
});
```

You can include the script inside the page, or save it as JavaScript file and include as a remote script file especially useful if you have a big data

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://yourdomain.com/blah/blah/blah/yourscript.js'></script>
```

I have used this with **no delays and issues** so far. **Tested it with a data of 54040 rows and works fine even with mobile devices**. I hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a source property that implements a function to compare the user input `term` with your data and pass the filtered values into `response`. Also, you need to provide the `label` and `value` property in your response array. These properties tell jQuery what to show on autocomplete suggestions and what to put in the textbox when user selects a value.

```js
var names = [{
    value: 'Jason',
    lastname: 'Borne'
  },
  {
    value: 'Jason',
    lastname: 'Derulo'
  },
  {
    value: 'Roberto',
    lastname: 'Carlos'
  },
  {
    value: 'Denzel',
    lastname: 'Washington'
  }
];

$('#names').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var term = request.term.toLowerCase();
    var filteredData = [];
    names.forEach(function(name) {
      if(name.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) >= 0 || name.lastname.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) >= 0) {
        filteredData.push({
          label: name.value + ' ' + name.lastname,
          value: name.value + ' ' + name.lastname
        })
      }
    });
    
    response(filteredData);
  },
  
  lookup: names,
  onSelect: function(suggestion) {
    alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ' ' + suggestion.lastname);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="names" id="names" />
```

Comment: Thanks Nisarg Shah for this solution. I trully appreciate :)

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to assist me.

Comment: Its works very good, however when the list is big, there is a delay and sometimes browser crashes. Is there a way to make it work for a big remote list?

Comment: Yeah, try adding the label and value properties to the source data. If they are available in source, you could save some performance cost during comparison and filter.

Answer (score 0):

See what happens when you change this

```
   var names = [
    { value: 'Jason', lastname: 'Borne' },
    { value: 'Jason', lastname: 'Derulo' },
    { value: 'Roberto', lastname: 'Carlos' },
    { value: 'Denzel', lastname: 'Washington' }
    ];
```

to this:

```
 var names = [
    { value: 'Jason Borne' },
    { value: 'Jason Derulo' },
    { value: 'Roberto Carlos' },
    { value: 'Denzel Washington' }
    ];
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to assist me.